# Access to font at '' from origin ' has been blocked by CORS policy wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

[image]

Access to font at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, then you can adjust the settings of your server Apache/Nginx or whatever to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your HTTP responses.

In your case, you probably want something like (this will allow your domain to access the fonts, but prevent other domains from using it, including your own subdomains):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.stubwire.com
I got the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header usage from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Here is another resource that gives examples of how to set up various servers (IIS, Nginx, Apache) to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header: http://support.maxcdn.com/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. But I don't understand how to fix it. Please tell me an easy way how to solve it. Thank you

Comment: Hello,
May I know which server and CDN you are using for your WordPress website?